# How to match overlapping perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get a regex to match an overlapping section when using /g. I believe I need to use lookbehind, but I'm having trouble understanding the documentation and getting it to match.

For example, the test case:

```
use feature ':5.18';
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use utf8;

my $test = '1 1 1';
$test =~ s/(?=[0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/$1$2/g;
say $test;      # still get '1 1 1'
```

How do I get rid of the spaces? The output should be '111'.

Comment: Why not just remove whitespace?

Comment: or else `s/(?<=[0-9])\s+(?=[0-9])//g`

Comment: I can't just remove whitespace because I only want to remove the white space between numbers.

Comment: Thank you: anubhava's answer works. I would appreciate an explanation for it if someone wants to write it up as an answer. For example, why are the numbers not deleted in the replace?

Comment: @anubhava post as answer.

Comment: You use a lookahead (that checks forward) at the wrong place, also you can avoid the capture groups, the references and the `+` quantifiers: `$test =~ s/[0-9]\K (?=[0-9])//g;`

Comment: @Rob `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind. It ensures what precedes matches without consuming characters. Casimir's example uses `\K` instead which resets the starting point of the match (all previously consumed characters are excluded from the final match). The `(?=)` is a positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches without consuming characters. The only *matched* characters in both cases are the whitespace characters between numbers. But I'm sure both of them will explain these tokens in their answer(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to remove spaces between digits you can use [zero-width look-arounds assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$test =~ s/(?<=[0-9])\s+(?=[0-9])//g;
```

**Breakup:**

- `(?<=[0-9])`: Assert that we have a digit at previous position
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=[0-9])`: Assert that we have a digit at next position

Comment: Great thank you: that is a helpful explanation and will help me to add another tool to my toolbox. A bonus would be to include Casimir's variation and ctwheels explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Problems are encountered when both adjacent digits are part of the match.

```
$test =~ s/([0-9])\s+([0-9])/$1$2/g;   # XXX Bad
```

Solutions:

```
$test =~ s/(?<=[0-9])\s+(?=[0-9])//g;
```

or the more efficient

```
$test =~ s/[0-9]\K\s+(?=[0-9])//g;   # 5.10+
```

In the former, the adjacent digits are never part of the match.

In the latter, only the preceding digit is part of the match.